# ESP32 Analog pin not reading when bluetooth is connected

Tags: c, arduino, esp32

I have been using ESP32 and writing code in Arduino. However, when I enable Bluetooth, GPIO4 and GPIO15 does not work to read analog inputs. I have connected IR LED's on both pins and reading analog signals. If Bluetooth code is not used, ESP32 is reading the analog signals and displaying it on serial monitor. If the below Bluetooth code is used, the reading is shown as 255 on both pins (reading 5v. Yes, they are 5v for now and will be level shifted to 3.3v).

Can someone please check and suggest a solution?

I have switched the sensors, removed them and whatever I do, the reading is the same when Bluetooth is read

Bluetooth code:

```
void init_bluetooth() {
      ESP_BT.begin("EKA Robot"); //Name of your Bluetooth Signal
      Serial.println("Bluetooth Device is Ready to Pair");
}
```

IR code:

```
    // Read Infrared LED on GPIO4. Similar function exists to read GPIO15
    int readIR() {
      int sensorValue = analogRead(oaPinL);
      delay(5);
      sensorValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 4095, 0, 255);
      return (sensorValue);
    }
```

I expect to read the sensor values. However, all it shows is 255. Does it mean it is somehow pulled high?

Comment: Is ESP32 5V tolerant?

Comment: @KentaroOkuda No, it is not 5V-tolerant.

Comment: Then, the pin may have been damaged when 5V was applied.

Comment: No. It is not damaged. I try using the same sensor after disabling Bluetooth and it works. I can assure pin is not damaged as it is able to read everything without Bluetooth. If someone knows about the library, please confirm if it is using some kind of a timer or interrupt which is disturbing these two pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two A/D converters in the ESP32 chip, ADC1 and ADC2. ADC2 pins can not be used when Wi-Fi or Bluetooth is used. Pins connected to ADC1 do work. These are GPIO32-36 and GPIO39.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks. Checking the ESP32 documentation again now.